# Server for iPhone app

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to build an application for iPhone with RSS feed but I don't know what server should be used for iPhone apps.

I have done this for Android using Apache Tomcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Apache Tomcat to build the server side of your application; the iPhone app will have no problems connecting to it. It is just the same as in your android app.